# Problem with burger menu, button not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There are 2 files, one is vue, the second is js. The js file contains an array, the problem is described in the console, in addition to this, there may be a problem with items, since it happens that the console issues the same error to it. I attach the code below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJut6.png) [image]

js file

```
import Vue from "vue";

new Vue ({
    el: 'TopHead',
    show:false
});
```

vue file "TopHead"

```
      <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <i class="material-icons menu" v-if="!show" @click="switchShow" key="menu">menu</i>
        <i class="material-icons clear" v-else @click="switchShow" key="clear">clear</i>
      </transition>
      <transition name="fade">
        <ul v-if="show">
          <li v-for="item in items" :key="item"><a :href="item.url">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </transition>
<script>

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [
        {name: 'Пряжа', url: '#'},
        {name: 'Спицы', url: '#'},
        {name: 'Крючки', url: '#'},
        {name: 'Аксессуары', url: '#'},
        {name: 'Подарочные сертификаты', url: '#'},
        {name: 'МК и описания', url: '#'},
        {name: 'Модели', url: '#'},
      ], show: false
    }
  },
  name: 'TopHead',
  methods: {
    switchShow() {
      this.show = this.show === false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with props you can get errors if you try to mutate them inside of the component which recieves the prop, instead of passing the new value to the parent and mutate it there. The problem shows here:

```
<i class="material-icons menu" v-if="!show" @click="show = !show" key="menu">menu</i>
```

In this case `@click="show = !show"` the click event mutates the the value of `show`. There are two ways to solve this.

> 1. Approach: Use `show` localy in your component

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: ['1','2','3'],
      show: false
    }
  },
  name: 'TopHead',
  methods: {
    switchShow() {
      this.show = this.show === false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

To mutate `show` in your component, you now use the `switchShow` function. On your icon you use it simply like this:

```
<i class="material-icons clear" v-else @click="switchShow" key="clear">clear</i>
```

> 2. Approach: emit the change to the parent

```
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: ['1','2','3']
    }
  },
  props: {
    show: Boolean
  },
  name: 'TopHead',
  methods: {
    emitShow() {
      this.$emit('emit-show');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<i class="material-icons clear" v-else @click="emitShow" key="clear">clear</i>
```

This is like calling a function on the parent (needs to be written seperately) to handle the mutation of `show`. If the parent mutates it within a function, probably in the same way we did in approach 1, then it will pass it´s new value down via props.

I would recommend you to use approach 1, as it is easier to understand and as long as no other component uses `show`, you can relocate it from your parent to your component.

---

**Edit for new occurred error**

As you need to use `v-model:key` while you using `v-if`, you need to hand a unique identifier. The problem is this:

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item">
```

... and ...

```
items: [
    {name: 'Пряжа', url: '#'},
    {name: 'Спицы', url: '#'},
    {name: 'Крючки', url: '#'},
    {name: 'Аксессуары', url: '#'},
    {name: 'Подарочные сертификаты', url: '#'},
    {name: 'МК и описания', url: '#'},
    {name: 'Модели', url: '#'},
  ], show: false
}
```

Each item in `items` is an object. If you try to apply them as a key, they simply print out like `[object Object]`, no matter if their values are different. To solve the problem, just use one of the objects value, like you did on the `<a>` tag:

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.name">
```

Comment: Whoa! Thank you, I understood how I needed to do it, I made 1 option. I was close, I got a mixture of 1 and 2 options. Only the console still shows errors, updated the photo post there

Comment: @Vasia Okay. Can you again please update the code to check, where the error is generated?

Comment: Done, the js file no longer exists if anything

Comment: Wow, thanks) Everything is clean and beautiful)

Comment: @Vasia Nice! If this helped you at all, it would be nice to vote for the answer, accept it to your question and mark some useful comments. Have fun with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Data needs to be a function that returns an object.

```js
//...
data() {
  return {
    items: ['1'],
    show: false
  }
}
```

EDIT: Ah, I just saw you're trying to merge .js file with .vue file.

Vue is giving you an error because in TopHead.vue there's no "items". You'd need to move the data() {} from the .js file to the .vue file, or change items and show to props.

Here I change them to props:

```html
<div id="TopHead">
  <top-head :items="myExternalItems"/>
</div>
```

```
//in your .js file
import TopHead from './TopHead.vue'
new Vue ({
    el: 'TopHead',
    components: {
       TopHead
    },
    data() {
      return {
        myExternalItems: ['1'],
      }
    }
});
```

In your `.vue` file:

```js
export default {
  props: ['show', 'items']
}
```

Comment: The error remains as in the picture, maybe you need a method to describe show and items?

Comment: Exactly, I forgot that I wanted to propose to translate the js file into vue)) And how can I do the same on vue? I'm just completely new to vue

Comment: I did it according to the YouTube guides, but there they connect the js file almost everywhere, of course it would be cooler on vue

Comment: did as you said, load empty site xD

Comment: @Vasia Can you please provide your current code and structure after the changes?

Comment: @Fabalance yes, only I did it a little differently, now everything works, only the error in the console is different, how can I show you the code?

Comment: @Fabalance ready, an error appears in the console if you click on the button, but the list also appears, I also have such a question, how to write a link in the array?

Comment: @Vasia Can you also add the new occured error to your question? I will try to give you a final answer then.

Comment: @Fabalance well, yes, there is an error in the screenshot in the post, so far this is the only error, and I still do not know how to assign references in the array

Comment: @Vasia I added my answer. Let me know if it helps by adding a comment to it.